# How to update only the given index of 2d array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I created a 2d array using Array constructor and filling it with a array inside it.

```
const a = new Array(26).fill(new Array(2).fill(-1));
```

When i try to do this `a[0][0] = 0` the 0th index of all 26 arrays have changed. How do I prevent that?

```js
const a = new Array(26).fill(new Array(2).fill(-1));
a[0][0] = 0

console.log(a)
```

Comment: That's quite intriguing...

Comment: [_"If the first parameter is an object, each slot in the array will reference that object."_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill).

Comment: `Array.from({ length: 26 }, () => new Array(2).fill(-1))` This will also work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const a = [...Array(26)].map(() => new Array(2).fill(-1))
a[0][0] = 0

console.log(a)
```